# Reparametrization of a Non-Smooth Curve to Make it Smooth

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametrization

How do we reparametrize the following curve to make it smooth? :

$A(t)=(t, \sqrt t)$ where $t \in [0, 1)$

Comment: $(t^2,t){}{}{}$?

Comment: Yes. I thought the same; but how to explain it mathematically. I mean "How did you derive this representation using the old representation by doing some mathematical abracadabra? Or it is just your intuition like the one I had?" I cannot reparametrize it using arc length function and get the result ($t^2, t$), I believe..